# Why is a beep sound produced when turning on a brushless DC (BLDC) motor?

Tags: electric-machine

Today, out of my 50 electric motors I noticed a beep sound is being produced whenever I turn a BLDC motor on. What actually vibrates in the motor and what actually vibrates it?

Comment: A "beep" and then nothing or do you mean a continuous buzz or hum?

Comment: It is a 'feature' of many motor controllers. The noise is caused by magnetostriction - that is the forces caused by the magnetism when the coils are activated. The motor controller utilises this to make the beep. Some even play little tunes.

Comment: @Transistor  Like Kartman Said when I use Controllers it plays little tune, But even without Controller, It gives a beep sound when running at low speeds

Comment: One use of the purposely made beep is to let the user know, or warn that something, the motor, is starting turning. Another example is my inductor cooker. When I switch on power, the beep warns me don't carelessly put any metallic thing on the cooker. Air con is another example.

Comment: If the controller uses a sensorless control, most likely it measures the reluctance in all directions to estimate the rotor position at the startup.